# Rewrite rule for user agent with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all requests to a domain from a particular user-agent to a subdomain. My rule is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Test Agent/(.*)$ // <-- Line 4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://test.domain.com/$1          [L,302]
```

But all I get when starting the web server is:

```
Syntax error on line 4 of /var/www/misafe/internal/misafe-old.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

It looks OK to me but I'm obviously missing something and the error is not helping much. Any ideas?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 2 bugs:

First:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Test Agent/(.*)$
```

You need to escape the space and forward slash in your regular expression pattern.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Test\ Agent\/(.*)$
```

Second:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://test.domain.com/$1          [L,302]
```

302 is a redirect HTTP status code, but you didn't specify that you are redirecting.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://test.domain.com/$1          [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly it! I can never seem to get Regex right no matter how much I try, it just seems foreign to me. Anyway the rules are working perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, the issue was not any regex escaping but rather the config file syntax escaping. Spaces are perfectly fine in the expression without escaping, but quotation marks should be used in the config file if there are (or might be) spaces.

Answer (score 1):

line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://test.domain.com/$1          [L,302]`

shuld be: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://test.domain.com/$1          [R=302]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was definitely part of the problem, the fact I hadn't escaped the regex properly was another issue.