# How to block a specific user agent in Apache

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I'm configuring my Django app to email me errors (exceptions).

Normally no problem - but my email is hosted on Office 365, and it seems that Microsoft is automatically scanning and loading URLs within emails.

The result is that it hits the URL in my Django app, and causes another error... and another email.  End result: a charming little mail loop which sends me 50+ messages within a few seconds.

I found entries like this in my apache logs:

```
157.55.39.163 - - [22/Aug/2018:17:30:05 +0000] "GET /testerror HTTP/1.1" 500 5808 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b"
```

I want to block access to the user agent (containing "BingPreview"), so I can prevent this loop.

I put this into my virtualhost:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "^.*BingPreview.*$" bad_user

<Directory /path/top/my/app/>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require not env bad_user
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

But when I reload apache, I get the error `negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive`.

Comment: I would use `mod_rewrite` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628075/7362396 - and after that RewriteCond the typical `RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]` to block it.

Comment: You may find this helpful - https://serverfault.com/questions/499327/how-can-i-block-a-user-agent-from-all-sites-on-my-server. I think you need to use `<Location>` directive instead of `<Directory>`.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasK, I used your idea and posted the solution below.

Comment: Be careful using `<Location>` as it overrides any other authorisation restrictions in `<Directory>`, unless you add `AuthMerging And`. See the security warning about `Require` in the apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it figured out.  Thanks for the tip, @Tobias K.

I enabled mod_rewrite because it wasn't already enabled.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then I put this into my virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*BingPreview.*$
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

And restarted apache to take effect:

```
service apache2 restart
```

And I can see in the apache log that BingPreview is getting blocked (note the 403):

`157.55.39.163 - - [22/Aug/2018:18:12:09 +0000] "GET /testerror HTTP/1.1" 403 4385 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b"`

Comment: This broken the rewrite of main website (wordpress). All links show a 404.

Comment: @e-info128 For all user-agents? By itself, the mod_rewrite directive above cannot do that. (?)

Comment: @e-info128 Fix your WordPress' `.htaccess` then.

Comment: When i read Tobias K. i thought: "lol i answered this?". Then i realized it was another Tobi ;-) You should change to "RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]", so it blocks also in the base directory when there is no index.php

Answer (score 6):

> But when I reload apache, I get the error `negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive`

`<RequireAny>` is the default "implied" container if not explicitly stated.

You can resolve this by doing something like the following instead:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "BingPreview" bad_user

<Directory /path/top/my/app/>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       <RequireAll>
       Require all granted
       Require not env bad_user
       </RequireAll>
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

The "regex" `BingReview` is the same as `^.*BingPreview.*$`.