# Blocking user agent

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Can someone tell me how to block the following user agent  using apache2 mod rewrite or any other method,

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/A1E1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972679/how-to-block-a-specific-user-agent-in-apache

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/A1E1*$
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]`

Something like this ?

Comment: No. Please read a short introduction into regular expression before trying to use a tool based on them.

Comment: In what _context_ are you wanting to do this? Server config? `.htaccess`? The syntax used in the `RewriteRule` directive above is intended to be used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: @MrWhite thank you for your reply. 
I want to add it in Apache2 VirtualHost, and I was wondering if thats the correct format or not. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block that specific user-agent in Apache config (or per-directory `.htaccess` file) using mod_rewrite, you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/A1E1"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This serves a 403 Forbidden for any request from that exact user-agent.

The regex (first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) `^` (start-of-string assertion) is successful for every request. Whilst the single `-` (hyphen) in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) indicates no substitution (we are simply blocking the request, not rewriting the URL).

By prefixing the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) with `=` makes it a lexicographical string comparison (ie. an exact match), not a regular expression. The surrounding double quotes are required since the string we are matching contains spaces.

The `F` flag is equivalent to `R=403`. The `L` flag is not required since it is *implied* when returning a non-3xx (or 2xx) status.

To return a "404 Not Found" instead of a "403 Forbidden" use the `R=404` flag instead of `F`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> can we add a wildcard entry like the last part of `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/A1E1` keeps changing the `/A1E1`

Yes, but you'll need to change the above *CondPattern* to a regex.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla/5\.0 (Windows NT 6\.1; WOW64; rv:63\.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/"
```

The above matches any user agent that *starts* `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/`, thus leaving the end of the user-agent variable.

Note that since this is now a regex any special regex meta characters need to be backslash-escaped. In this example, that would seem to be just the dots (`.`). The surrounding double quotes can still be used to avoid having to escape the spaces.

Comment: Thank you  . it worked, can we add a wildcard entry like the last part of `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/A1E1` keeps changing the _/A1E1_