# Apache - allow only requests from browser

Tags: apache

How can I check whether a request came from a browser, a non-browser http client or the command line and allow only requests from browsers (Does not need to be non-hackable, just a convenient solution).

I am assuming standard browsers only (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, MS Edge, Safari) –

```
<If "Request does not come from Browser">
  Require all denied 
</If>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block a specific user agent in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972679/how-to-block-a-specific-user-agent-in-apache)

Comment: Additional context: as the information about the user agent can be faked pretty simply, this cannot be made very secure

Comment: yes, I am aware of that, but this should be okay for the use case.

Comment: Then feel free to share your attempts, and a specific problem statement

Comment: It does not really answer my question, since I need to know what regex to use that matches Browsers but not non-Browsers.

Comment: I doubt that there is a complete list of all user agents, so any attempt to write a regular expression for that would also block regular users (like those who configured their browser to not send a user agent at all)

Comment: Ok, I am assuming standard browsers only (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, MS Edge, Safari)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it